# Не вижу раздел ext4 на винте после перестановки его из SATA в USB

Tags: linux, ext4, gpt

В моём ноутбуке есть два винта:

```
1. SSD 240Gb GPT, EXT4 (linux mint x64)
2. HDD 1Tb GPT, EXT4 (диск с личными данными)
```

Когда HDD воткнут в SATA:

```
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print
[sudo] password for and: 
Модель: ATA HGST HTS541010A9 (scsi)
Диск /dev/sdb: 1953525168s
Размер сектора (логич./физич.): 512B/4096B
Таблица разделов: gpt

Номер  Начало  Конец        Размер       Файловая система  Имя  Флаги
 1     2048s   1953523711s  1953521664s  ext4
```

Если я вынимаю HDD из SATA вставляю в USB, то вижу это:

```
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print
[sudo] password for and: 
Ошибка: Недопустимый аргумент во время позиционирования для чтения на /dev/sdb
Повторить/Retry/Игнорировать/Ignore/Отменить/Cancel? I
Ошибка: Резервная таблица GPT повреждена, но главная кажется корректной, поэтому она и будет использоваться.
OK/Отменить/Cancel? O                                                     
Backtrace имеет 8 вызовов из стека:
  8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(ped_assert+0x31) [0x7fa4f3bc34b1]
  7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(+0x3f686) [0x7fa4f3bf3686]
  6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.0(ped_disk_new+0x49) [0x7fa4f3bc8f99]
  5: parted() [0x406dff]
  4: parted(non_interactive_mode+0x8f) [0x40dc5f]
  3: parted(main+0x146d) [0x4064ed]
  2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fa4f33a1f45]
  1: parted() [0x406617]


You found a bug in GNU Parted! Here's what you have to do:

Don't panic! The bug has most likely not affected any of your data.
```

dmesg при подключении пишет:

```
[  469.087268] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  469.180851] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=3e40
[  469.180859] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  469.180865] usb 2-1.1: Product: ZM-VE350
[  469.180869] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: ZALMAN
[  469.180874] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 303030303030303030303030
[  469.181387] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  469.181599] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[  470.180903] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ZALMAN   ZM-VE350         1060 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  470.181546] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  470.182092] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953461760 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[  470.183094] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  470.183099] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 3f 00 10 08
[  470.184336] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  470.184342] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  470.189628]  sdb: unknown partition table
[  470.211855] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

fdisk:

```
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for and: 

ВНИМАНИЕ: На '/dev/sdb' обнаружена GPT (GUID Partition Table)! Утилита fdisk не поддерживаетGPT. Используйте GNU Parted.


Диск /dev/sdb: 1000.2 Гб, 1000172421120 байт
255 головок, 63 секторов/треков, 121597 цилиндров, всего 1953461760 секторов
Units = секторы of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Размер сектора (логического/физического): 512 байт / 512 байт
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Идентификатор диска: 0x1988302a

Устр-во Загр     Начало       Конец       Блоки   Id  Система
/dev/sdb1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $
```

Так же я не могу просмотреть содержимое раздела ни на каком другом компьютере.Пробовал использовать другой внешний бокс для HDD, пробовал на компах с виндой - безрезультатно!  **Почему так?**

Я вообще хочу переустановить систему, но боюсь, что потом не увижу свой раздел sdb1

dmesg при другом боксе:

```
[  354.312604] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  354.494908] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=5030
[  354.494915] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  354.494920] usb 2-1.1: Product:  FA GOFlex Desk
[  354.494923] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  354.494927] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 01234567
[  354.496498] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  354.496870] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[  355.904984] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  USB 3.0 Cable    0214 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  355.905659] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  355.906189] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[  355.907250] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  355.907260] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
[  355.910711] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  355.910717] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  355.963329] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[  355.963355]  sdb: sdb1
[  355.967098] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  356.584336] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  357.424767] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[  357.424782] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  357.424785] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  357.424788] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  357.424790] Read(10): 28 00 53 c0 0c 10 00 00 c8 00
[  357.424800] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1405094928
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $
```

На удивление другой бокс на моём компе заработал!!!
Я до этого его(другой бокс) просто пробовал на компе с WINDOWS7, там тоже раздел не видел, а на своём так и не попробовал. В общем ZALMAN 350 - ЗЛО!!!

Comment: А `fdisk -l` показывает что-то, когда диск подключён через USB? В dmesg'е что пишется, когда подключаете его?

Comment: [как вставить код или предварительно отформатированный текст](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Ваш диск просто не определяется в системе, раз fdisk "ничего не показывает"...

Comment: Собственно почему не определяется то?

Comment: Заметьте: при прямом подключении (sata) размер диска определяется как `1953525168 * 512` байт, а через usb - `1953461760 * 512` байт. Разница большая, т.е. ваш usb-box врёт. Вы говорите, что пробовали другой бокс, что `dmesg` говорит о нём?

Comment: На другом боксе заработало! хотя fdisk что про залман-бокс, что про другой нонейм-бокс абсолютно одинаковую инфу показывает

Comment: Про другой бокс dmesg говорит, что размер диска `1953525167 * 512` байт, т.е. ровно на один блок (512 байт) меньше, чем нужно. Это тоже нехорошо. Ну и `end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1405094928` как-то тревожно.